Ubuntu VM won't boot completely after OS update
I'll try to keep it short to start.
We use Veeam to perform backups of our VMs in our VMWare environment. This uses a system of proxies and a repository server, all running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
We also use a third-party system (Arctic Wolf) to scan our environment for security vulnerabilities. Recently, this scan started to flag these proxies and repositories as being at risk since the OS was out of date.
I did the simplest process I know of to update the OS, which I have done before with no issues.
sudo -s
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get full-upgrade -y
apt-get autoremove -y
apt-get autoclean -y

During the upgrade process I received a notice that the kernels didn't match, and I should restart after the upgrade completed to make sure it was updated. I did this.
After this update, the proxy servers are fine, but the repository server is completely broken.
This error appears: Failed to start default target: Transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive

The boot process continues for a while, with other errors showing up.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/veeam-vg/veeam-lg
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /home/administrator/veeamrepo
[DEPEND] Failed for Local File Systems
[FAILED] Failed to start Set Up Additional Binary Formats

Boot eventually finishes and states "You are in emergency mode."
OK, that wasn't very short.
I have done some researching (Googling) and I see a lot of references to "fstab" needing to be revised somehow.
I know so SO LITTLE about Linux. I was only a passenger as an engineer we contracted built out these servers. Can anyone possibly tell me if I am heading down the right path here? I can provide more info from the busted server, I'll gladly do it, just let me know.
Thank you for any help you can provide!
EDIT 1 @ Thomas Ward
I see this in /dev/mapper:
root@veeamrepo-edw:/dev# ls
control    ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

Here is the contents of /etc/fstab, as well as the blkid output:
root@veeamrepo-edw:/etc# cat fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>  <type>  <options>   <dump>   <pass>
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-hKPBa7n51jMbBFC0DL1QlugRuASFVqlsxq544ZzaDDUMVVuvk0XFX086fU0L1q6x / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2dcc3f50-b51a-4fb6-891b-e0da350c963 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swapsw      0       0
/dev/veem-vg/veeam-lg /home/administrator/veeamrepo     xfs defaults        0       0

root@veeamrepo-edw:/etc# blkid
/dev/mapper/ubunutu--vg-ubunutu--lv: UUID="10c9ed7e-a705-4837-9a9b-afb08c4c88a0" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="2dcc3f50-b51a-4fb6-891b-e0da350c963" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="94fba7e1-ff79-435d-84e6-9e6792f0fc16"
/dev/sda3: UUID="F8esYk-gSCj-P13A-vxIn-M3xy-2A6n-c1uD1v" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="95235f35-7573-49cd-8ae6-dea94fb0b363"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="9cb32045-fcef-4e44-b4d0-1366dad9078e"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"


In Emergency Mode, do you see anything when you do ls /dev/mapper/ that says 'veeam' in it?  What's the contents of your /etc/fstab?

Edited post to add this info

Your veem-vg and veeam-lg volumes are no longer available on the system. They don't show in blkid either, so either the logical volume is gone or something else critical happened to the system.  You will have to comment out the line that says /dev/veem-vg/veeam-lg in your /etc/fstab file in order to get out of emergency mode and back to a 'functional' system.  From there, you need to start investigating why this veeam logical volume disappeared.
